# Differentiate between custom timer jobs and system timer jobs sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to differentiate between custom timer jobs and system timer jobs. Under Central Administration - Monitoring - Job Definitions I see all the jobs defined on the farm. I´m new to this farm and I need to get an overview over all custom/created timer jobs. Unfortunately no special naming conventions were followed and there is no one to ask.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sharepoint powershell to get some details that you need, run the command below to return a list of Jobs.

`Get-SPTimerJob -WebApplication "http://webapplication" | select Name, DisplayName, Status, TypeName`

The return type is a SPJobDefinition and Name, DisplayName, Status, TypeName are members of SPJobDefinition.

I don't see an option for "custom" but if you look at the namespaces of "TypeName" you should be able to work out any custom Job becuase the default ones begin with Microsoft.SharePoint! Not an ideal solution but could get you started.

A link to SPJobDefinition

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition_members(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Usually its a good idea to create custom timer jobs with company name. So for my example I name all my timer jobs like

```
MyCompany.TimerJob1
MyCompany.TimerJob2
```